# Can ghosts eat other ghosts to increase their strength?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e

I have not been able to track down much in the way of ghosts for the New World of Darkness, but I am curious about one thing in particular. I know that spirits can consume other spirits to increase their Essence, but I am not sure how that occurs.

My question is, can a ghost do the same? I am looking at creating a Ghost Ally and I would like to know if it'd be possible to have it become stronger through consuming other ghosts. If not by this method, are there any other ways a ghost could become stronger, especially with the help of a mortal on its side? I would prefer answers from the books, but I am open to homebrew answers as well. Thank you.

Comment: I mean growing in Rank. The Book of Spirits discusses how a Rank 3 dog-spirit will be stronger than a Rank 1 dog-spirit, but how does it reach that higher rank? The book seems to insinuate that it is through consuming Essence through its example of One-Girl's-Ecstasy, but it doesn't discuss how that occurs, or how much Essence they need to consume for it.

Answer (score 4):

## Depends

Is God-Machine Chronicle stuff allowed?

- **Yes**: Get the book and check the **Essence Thief** numen on p229.
- **No**: though luck. Try to bribe your storyteller!

Handy link with an overview of [Numen](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Numina_(WOD)) powers.

### Where to find Ghosts:

- New World of Darkness Core rulebook p208: basic information
- Book of the Dead: way more info, but this is more directed towards the Underworld and how it interacts with other supernaturals.
- Geist: The Sin-Eaters: describes a new splat of mortals that made a deal with a certain type of ghosts (Perhaps you should check this; seems quite close to what you want)?

I'm sure there is more, but those are of the top of my head.

### Spirits

Check **Regaining Essence** on p135 of Book of Spirits. It's not "consuming", it's theft. If all Essence is drained away in this manner, the target falls into slumber (in which it stays until it gains Essence somehow).

## Moar Power

In general ghosts only gain power by sticking around (see Numina section of the New World of Darkness Core rulebook p210). The God-Machine Chronicle book describes some way that Ghosts or Spirits become more powerful (see p216 & 217), but there's no detailed 12 step guide.

The only ingame way that's more or less described is the **Old Soul** Numen from **Mummy: The Curse** (see p209). But:

- This is a rare Numen (so check with your ST)
- Why would a ghost of that age be interested in you?

Have you checked with the ST whether he allows your Ally to gain power?

Comment: I know about the Geists and I think they are awesome, but I doubt my Storyteller would allow that. Geists are considered just below Mages in ranking and in the exponential curve, and we are just mortals. Vampires were considered too powerful for the campaign. I'm kind of surprised he is letting me get the Ghost Ally that can't be harmed by ordinary weapons...